# How to plot a graph of pandas dataframe rows using matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

A small snipet of my dataframe is given below.

```
       UserID                Recommendations
 0      A001        [(B000OR5928, 5.671419620513916), (B000A1HU1G, 5.435572624206543), (B0039HBNMA, 5.4260640144348145), (B000EEGAJW, 5.502416133880615), (B001L8KE06, 5.508320331573486), (B0002ZO60I, 5.640686511993408), (B0002D0096, 5.543562412261963), (B0013PU75Y, 5.452023506164551), (B005M0TKL8, 5.481754302978516), (B001PGXHYO, 5.5017194747924805)]
 1      A002        [(B000EEGAJW, 4.382242679595947), (B004ZKIHVU, 4.182255268096924), (B000CBE3GE, 4.242227077484131), (B000CCJP4I, 4.354374408721924), (B000VBC5CY, 4.342846393585205), (B0002KZHQA, 4.127199649810791), (B0026RB0G8, 4.246310234069824), (B0002D0CQC, 4.275753021240234), (B0002M6CVC, 4.679849624633789), (B0002D0KOG, 4.138158321380615)]
```

The dataframe contains two columns UserID and Recommendations.The recommendation column contains productID of products recommended to that user along with ratings which is in the form of list.

What I want to do is if I click on user A001 then a graph should get display.The y-axis of graph will display productIDs recommended to A001 and X-axis will display rating of that product.This should be done in case of each UserID

I know how to plot a graph with single values using matplotlib but here it has a list of values .How can I go about it.

Comment: Please show some code! People will be more likely to help if you provide evidence that you've given it a good go.

Comment: Yes I am working on it.Soon I will edit it with some code as even I am not getting how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code to solve your problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for i in df.UserID:
  ratings = []
  productsIDs = []

  for points in df.Recommendations[np.where(df.UserID==i)[0]]:
    for point in points:
      ratings.append(point[1])
      productsIDs.append(point[0])

    plt.plot(ratings, productsIDs)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Hey,Thanks for trying.But this is not working for me.

Comment: Not an error message but the graphs are not showing correct result.It is taking wrong scale for ratings and ProductID is not shown on y-axis.Even plotting is not showing up,just x and y axis.I am trying to sort it properly.

Comment: I edited my code, I made some mistakes with the x and y axis names, now it should works.